# How to stack multiple absolute divs of variable height from bottom of a container

Tags: css

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative; height: 500px">
  <div class="stack1">
    multi line content
  </div>
  <div class="stack2">
    multi line content
  </div>
</div>
```

I want both 'stack2' and 'stack1' to be docked to the bottom of container with 'stack1' on top of 'stack2'.

I know how to do it with just one stack, by setting the div as absolute and bottom:0

Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.stack1,
.stack2 {
    position: absolute;
}
.stack2 {
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
}
.stack1 {
    bottom: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

The height of stack2 should be the bottom value of stack1. See: http://jsfiddle.net/355nZ/

EDIT:

If the height of the two items is unknown, you'd have to nest the two blocks in another container that you could then stick to the bottom. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/355nZ/1/

Comment: lets consider the scenario where the height of both stack1 and stack2 is unknown? how would you solve it?

Comment: @sheaujye Can you nest the two blocks in another container? See my updated answer.